# Passing $scope.Variable to another function to set the value in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So say I have this function which assigns value to the $scope.Variable

```
 function Tasker($http,$scope,angularServiceMessageVariable)
{
  angularServiceMessageVariable = "some data";    
}
```

and I call it with this

```
 function RunLockExpirationNotificationService($scope, $http, $spinner, $actions) {
            $scope.runService = function () {                 

Tasker($http,$scope,$scope.LockExpirationNotificationServiceMessage);                

    };        
        }
```

I am getting undefined angularServiceMessageVariable which is basically the $scope.variable that I am passing to the method. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here. I need to set the value of a scope variable in another function. I tried $parse but that gives me undefined exception.

Thanks

Comment: use $scope.angularServiceMessageVariable to refer scope level variable

Comment: can you please provide an example.

Comment: you are passing `$scope.variable` by call by value, so it will be copied to local variable `angularServiceMessageVariable` so modification wont affect actual value

Comment: so either change `$scope.angularServiceMessageVariable`  or `$scope.LockExpirationNotificationServiceMessage` directly. than changing a local copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the name of the variable you want to add to the scope instead. Change to:

```
function Tasker($http,$scope,angularServiceMessageVariable)
{
  $scope[angularServiceMessageVariable] = "some data";    
}
```

and

```
 function RunLockExpirationNotificationService($scope, $http, $spinner, $actions) {
            $scope.runService = function () {                 

Tasker($http,$scope,'LockExpirationNotificationServiceMessage');                

    };        
        }
```

Comment: Exactly what I asked for..Thanks Joao